# 64bit windows guest on a 64bit linux host with root

Tags: linux, ubuntu, virtualbox, root

I've installed virtualbox on Ubuntu using the regular package.

When I run virtualbox as a normal user, I can create VMs it lets me create VMs with both 32 and 64 bit guest OSes.
But when I run virtualbox as root (using sudo or otherwise), it only allows me to create 32 bit guest OSes.

Running as root is critical since for me I'm trying to run my dual-boot Windows installation as a guest VM (through the procedure detailed [here](http://www.qc4blog.com/?p=483)).

Answer (score 3):

I don't think you need to run as root for your need.

Let's have a look to your hard disk device file. It should looks like this:

```
▶ ls -l /dev/sda
brw-rw---- 1 root disk 8, 0 Nov 27 15:16 /dev/sda
```

Hence every users added to the group `disk` can raw read the hard drive which is what you actually need. The group name might vary on your system. Just add yourself to that group, logout/logon for this to take effect and give it another try without root privileges.

Comment: Nice one, didn't notice the special group!